# Settings.bundle name still hard-coded?

Tags: ios, xcode

Last time I read up about providing app preferences in iOS, the setting bundle name was hard-coded to `Settings.bundle`. I couldn't find a recent version of the guide in the latest Xcode's developer docs. Where is the settings bundle format and placement documented, please? It's not under "Bundle resources", where Info.plist is documented.

My real question is - is the bundle name still hard-coded, so that different apps/targets in the same project can't have different settings bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is official [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) about this bundle.

Actually, I did not meet any problem with using by default created bundle with name `Settings.bundle`, as kept every target in separated physical folder. However if there is high needs to keep them aside in one folder, it is possible by using different names for these resources (eg. `Settings-target1.bundle`, `Settings-target2.bundle`, etc.), but in finally built target application bundle they MUST be named `Setting.bundle` (by requirement; actually no one complains why `Localizable.strings`, say, named as it is), so you just need to rename every corresponding `Settings-x.bundle` into `Settings.bundle` during application build process, say in custom Copy/Script phase.

Comment: I already do the rename-on-build trick. Works, but prevents parallel builds. And I saw that doc. It's super old - just look at the screenshots. I was hoping they've revised that since.